# Of rationals converging to Pi

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $f$, for $x>0$, is a continuous function such that for all rationals $m=p/q$ with $\gcd(p,q)=1$, $f(m)$ is equal to the number of digits of $q$ (either base-2 or base-10), what is $f(\pi)$?

And 2) If $f(m)=q$, then what is $f(\pi)$?

Comment: What makes you think such a function can even exist?

Comment: at least not a continuous one...

Comment: "and 2) If f(m)=2", what does it mean?

Comment: I dont know. It says "And 2) If f(m)=q"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such a function cannot possibly exist. To see this, first observe

$$f\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)=\left\lfloor \log_b \, n \right\rfloor \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\infty.$$

All the while, $(n+1)/n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$ but $f(1)=1\ne\infty$, which contradicts continuity.

This same example applies to case (2) as well.